# Is incense smoke bad for a laptop?

Tags: laptop

I like to burn incense pretty often; the smoke is calming and it smells great.

Often, I have it lit on my desk, near my laptop because the smell is stronger and it's just soothing for me to watch the smoke go by.

Is it likely that the smoke will do anything to my laptop? Get stuck in keys or be sucked up by the fan or something?

Comment: Hm, I'm going to try this out. It's amazing the type of things you learn on SU heh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been doing the same for years and never had a problem. As long as you don't drive the smoke onto your laptop (as dense smoke goes upwards if there is no significant air current in the room), I don't see any possibility of damage. Just keep up having the nice ambiance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would be that good for a computer. If you wish to continue doing this (understandable). Just go out and buy some canned air, and spray it out like once a month or so. When I say spray it out, I mean it would take like 1 minute for a quick job. 10 minutes if you want to be thorough and open it up and spray the insides.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and couldn't find any research regarding this interesting question, but I did found [this](http://www.ryansccs.com/cigarette-damage-computer.html) site that urges you to keep any smoke away from the laptop. I don't think the particles in incense smoke won't accumulate in your laptop either.

A laptop can be a *pain* to clean depending on the way it's built and how accessible the fan is. As Mehper says, you should at the very least keep the smoke or fumes from getting into your laptop.